# How can i sort a pair of array of vectors v[ ]by second element

Tags: sorting, vector

I have a pair of array of vectors {V[x].push_back(make_pair(y,w));}
I want to sort it by the second element ie. by w.How could it be done in c++?

Comment: `std::sort` passing a compare function: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort  (3)

Comment: Are you asking how to sort an array, or how to compare the vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the comparing function as the third parameter to the sort function. Like you mentioned your vector is something of the form:

```
 {V[x].push_back(make_pair(y,w));}
```

Then the comparing function will look like:

```
bool greaterThan( pair<int,int> lx, pair<int,int> rx ){
    return lx.second < rx.second; //change here for different criterias
}

//used as
sort(V[x].begin(), V[x].end(), greaterThan);
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand. Edit: Corrected

Comment: Or using a lambda exp. : `std::sort(V[x].begin(), V[x].end(), [](std::pair<int, int> a, std::pair<int, int> b){ return a.second < b.second; });`

Comment: Actually you need to pass `greaterThan` without parenthesis.

Comment: You are right @nngmg. If using c++ provided `greater<int>` comparator function, then only we need those parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: @VishalTheBeast actually I had the undirected graph with v[x].push_back(make_pair(y,w)) and v[y].push_back(make_pair(x,w)) and i wanted to sort by w. Should sort(V[x].begin(), V[x].end(), greaterThan); work or i should pass y in V?

Comment: You may be wanting to sort your vertices by weights. It depends on your algorithm but you can sort them this way without any problem, I guess.